# Extract a value from an OpenStruct Ruby object

Tags: ruby, data-structures

I get the following Ruby object returned (from a query to the Google Analytics API using the [garb gem](https://github.com/Sija/garb), comes from the sample call shown on the README.md there, `Exits.results(profile, :filters => {:page_path.eql => '/'})`)

```
> data.results
=> [#<OpenStruct page_path="/", exits="3706", pageviews="10440">]
```

I'd to extract the pageviews value (10440), but cannot figure out how to do it. I see that my object, `data.results` is class `array` of length `1`, but data.first is class `OpenStruct` with a return value that looks almost identical:

```
irb(main):140:0> data.results.class
=> Array
irb(main):141:0> data.results.length
=> 1
irb(main):142:0> data.first
=> #<OpenStruct page_path="/", exits="3706", pageviews="10440">
irb(main):143:0> data.first.class
=> OpenStruct
```

while `data` itself seems to be a custom return type called `ResultsSet`:

```
irb(main):144:0> data.class
=> Garb::ResultSet
irb(main):145:0> data
=> #<Garb::ResultSet:0x00000002411070 @results=[#<OpenStruct page_path="/", exits="3706", pageviews="10440">], @total_results=1, @sampled=false>
irb(main):146:0>
```

Lots of data structures, but no idea how to get my desired value out. I gathered `OpenStruct` was related to a hash, so I thought `data.first["pageviews"]` would do it,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<OpenStruct page_path="/", exits="3706", pageviews="10440">
    from (irb):146
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Meanwhile `data.first.keys` returns `nil`.  No idea how to get my data out, (short of converting the length-1 array, `data.results` to a string and parsing with grep, which seems *crazy*.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```
data.first.pageviews
```

Comment: Yup, that worked!  Thanks much.  Not sure I understand the logic entirely, but very helpful!

Comment: Is this a feature that changed in ruby 1.9 or something?